# Show question instead of feed when the 'back' button is pressed

Tags: feature-request, android-app

When I use the new android app for the stackexchange network, answers aren't shown directly under the question but on another view. I have to press a button 'answers' to see them.

But when I'm on the page with the answers and press the 'back' button of my phone, I'm send right back to the feed instead of to the question.

For me, this is very counter intuitive and I often find myself back on the feed only because I wanted to look something up on the question.

So please, could you change the behaviour of the 'back' button to show me the question when I'm on the page for the answers?

Comment: Just swipe back.

Comment: This works, as long as I scroll exactly right - otherwise I open the panel on the right hand side. And it doesn't change the the 'back' button doesn't do what (I think) it's expected to do:bringing me back to the last view.